# How to update DV360 creative headline & description using API or Graph explorer?

Tags: api, google-api

I want to update the DV360 Creative headline and description, but I am not able to find the proper request JSON element.

I have try from client

https://developers.google.com/display-video/api/reference/rest/v2/advertisers.creatives/patch?apix_params=%7B%22advertiserId%22%3A843115633%2C%22creativeId%22%3A492353092%2C%22updateMask%22%3A%22displayName%22%2C%22resource%22%3A%7B%22displayName%22%3A%22New%20sid%22%7D%7D